# Python- syntax error "if statement"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting one and the same error message (even though just yesterday everything was working just fine). Nothing has been changed in the code since then.

Here is the code itself:

```
x = [1, 4, 34, 56, 8, 5, 8, 6, 5, 12, 89, 23]  

z = int(input('Please eneter a number to check: ')    
if x.count(z) >= **2 :** *This is where it gives me a syntax error*        
    print('There are:', x.count(z), 'numbers of', z, 'in the list')    
elif x.count(z) > 0 < 2:        
    print('This number is unique in the list')
else:
    print('There is no such number in the list')
```

Any ideas why it might be happening?

Comment: You missed a ) in end of your input line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what syntax error you are getting since you didn't state it explicitly. But I believe you missed a closing parenthesis  for your z variable. Here is the fixed code, and it works for me:

```
x = [1, 4, 34, 56, 8, 5, 8, 6, 5, 12, 89, 23]

z = int(input('Please eneter a number to check: '))

if x.count(z) >= 2 :
    print('There are:', x.count(z), 'numbers of', z, 'in the list')
elif x.count(z) > 0 < 2:
    print('This number is unique in the list')
else:
    print('There is no such number in the list')
```

Comment: Thank you John, you are absolutely right. Thank you for pointing out. How could I miss it... : (

Comment: You are welcome. You can use an editor that easily points out such syntax errors